# Decode bytes without losing data

Tags: python, gzip, python-3.7, zlib

Input is a byte variable with value as `b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00'` and need it to be converted to string.
Expected output is `'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00'`.

How do I achieve this?

I am using zlib to get the input gzip data and need to convert to string for browser for it unzip.

I have tried adding the `errors='ignore'` parameter.

I tried providing 'latin1' encoding, but browser is unable to unzip the data.

```
>>> a = b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00'
>>> z = a.decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
>>> z = a.decode('utf-8', errors = 'ignore')
>>> z
'\x1f\x08\x00'
```

Expected result `'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00'`

Comment: Can you print what the output of a is before you try to decode it and post it here? You might only need to use the srt() function.

Comment: `print(str(z).strip('b'))`? It's not clear why you would want this output.

Comment: Did you mean `a.hex()`?

Comment: Are you sure the browser  isn't expected the zipped data encoded to a base64 string?  Base64 encoding is how binary blobs are usually passed around in the web world.

Comment: @chepner: need this to be sent to browser. The extra b' causes content-length mismatch. Its a zlib compressed output which returned bytets.

Comment: @Uber: str() function adds extra \ to the existing \. Need to just remove b'

Comment: `str` doesn't add anything; you're looking at the result of `repr(str(z))`, not the contents of the string itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string and strip the unwanted characters:

```
z = b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00'
a = str(z)[2:-1]
print(a)
print(type(a))
```

Output:

```
\x1f\x8b\x08\x00
<class 'str'>
```

Usage in Python3.7:

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 17 2019, 13:54:58)
[Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00'
>>> b = str(a)[2:-1]
>>> b
'\\x1f\\x8b\\x08\\x00'
>>> print(b)
\x1f\x8b\x08\x00
>>>
```

Comment: ```>>> a = b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00'
>>> b = str(a)[2:-1]
'\\x1f\\x8b\\x08\\x00'```
I am expecting a '\x1f\x8b\x08\x00'

Comment: Double backslashes are the internal Python representation! You need to print to stdout or write the variable into a file the see the string as it is. Try: `print(b)`

Comment: Do you see the differences between just calling `b` and `print(b)` ...